# Is there a "Planck law" for any type of field/particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

When looking at the derivation of Planck's law, I wondered if we could do the same derivation for **any** field, not just the electromagnetic field. Is it indeed possible? Is there an equivalent of Planck's law for any type of field?

Comment: You might find this interesting if maybe not directly relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific form of Planck's law depends on mainly two properties of the field. The first is the spin, which tells you what kind of statistics it follows. The statistics tells you how many particles lie in a certain state at a given temperature. In the case of EM fields, it has spin 1, so it follows the Bose-Einstein statistics. The second is the dispersion relation, which in turn determines the density of states, which then tells you effectively how many states there are that have a certain energy. Photons have a linear dispersion relation, which in 3D gives a density of states that is proportional to the square of energy. So yes, if we were given a field that still follows Bose-Einstein statistics, but has a different dispersion relation, we could get the Planck's law for that particle that looks different from the one for photons.

Let me expand on that with specific examples. For ease of illustration, let's also use the frequency distribution. Planck's law tells us that the spectral radiance of radiation exiting a small hole on a cavity full of photon gas is 
$$B_\nu(T) = \frac{c}{4\pi} u_\nu(T)\sim \frac{(h\nu)^3}{e^{h\nu/k_B T} - 1} \>.$$
Here $u_\nu(T)$ is the spectral energy density function, which gives us the distribution of energy in each mode ($\nu$) at a given temperature. $B_\nu(T)$ and $u_\nu(T)$ are directly proportional like this because radiation is the same in all directions.

The expression for $u_\nu$ is derived via statistical mechanical properties of the system. Suppose the total energy of the system is $U(T)$, we want to find out how $U(T)$ is distributed into modes with different energy, which means we want to know what is $dU/d\epsilon$. $U(T)$ can be written as the integral
$$U(T) = \int_0^\infty n(\epsilon, T) g(\epsilon)\epsilon d\epsilon \>. $$
The integrand is the spectral energy distribution we want. Note that it is called spectral because the spectral distribution of the radiation in frequency can be rewritten as a function of energy given the dispersion relation. Here $n(\epsilon, T)$ is the mean occupation number of a given state with energy $\epsilon$ at a given temperature $T$. For a free Bose-Einstein field (particles in a box), it is $(e^{\beta\epsilon} - 1)^{-1}$, where $\beta = 1/k_B T$ is the reciprocal temperature. This tells us at a certain temperature, how many particles are in a certain state with energy $\epsilon$. $g(\epsilon)$ is the density of states, which tells us how many states are available with this energy. This can be derived from the dispersion relation, which relates the wave vector $k$ (or momentum $\hbar k$) to the energy. To find out how they are specifically related, you can refer to the Wikipedia page on [density of states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_states). Most often the density of states depends on $\epsilon$ by a power law, $g(\epsilon)\sim \epsilon^m$. In the case of photons, the dispersion relation is $ \epsilon = \hbar k c $, and as a result $m = 2$. Knowing $n(\epsilon, T)$ and $g(\epsilon)$, we then basically have Planck's law, $$u_\epsilon(T) \sim \epsilon \times \frac{1}{e^{\beta\epsilon} - 1} \times \epsilon^2 =\frac{\epsilon^3}{e^{\beta\epsilon} - 1} \>. $$

Note that this derivation is quite general, and $u_\epsilon(T) = n(\epsilon) g(\epsilon) \epsilon $ is always true. So if we had a different field with a different dispersion relation, say for example $\epsilon \sim k^2$ instead of $\epsilon \sim k$, we would have a density of states $g(\epsilon)\sim \epsilon^{1/2}$, which would give $u_\epsilon \sim \epsilon^{3/2}/(e^{\beta\epsilon} - 1) $.

Of course, the question of how useful this is still remains. Even if we found out the spectral energy distribution of some field, it doesn't necessarily have the same significance as the EM field. The field might interact with matter very differently, and we might not really want of conceive of it as a "radiation".

Comment: What if we had Fermi-Dirac statistics? We would have a different number of states per unit of volume, but we could carry out the same derivation, no?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. In fact, if we consider the extreme relativistic case, a fermion will have the same density of states as the photon, so the Planck's law will look almost the same as that for the photon, except the $-$ sign in the denominator becomes a $+$ sign.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

Supernovae produce thermal neutrinos and antineutrinos of all species (in addition to electron-neutinos produce by inverse beta decay)--this is a Weak interaction. Meanwhile, in heavy ion collisions, thermal pions are emitted by hot nuclear matter (a Strong interaction).

Comment: Nice! - What would be a good, general definition for "thermal"? We are beyond thermal being associated with photons, right?

Comment: I suppose "thermal" is shorthand for thermal equilibrium--that is, energy is being shared between available degrees of freedom.